# Value of multi-author vs single author papers in academic performance review

Tags: evaluation-criteria

I am having some disagreement with my VP Academic. She claims that being one of three or four authors (not necessarily the first) in a published paper has the same value of being the only author.

Does anyone know of academic evaluation criteria for publications published or used by reputable institutions? Or, can anyone suggest other effective ways to prove her wrong?

Post comments edit:

1) I publish in the field of statistical methods with data analysis included. My papers are being compared with papers in social sciences.

2) For value I mean time and effort put in writing the papers and getting them published.

3) I would like to find out if there exist some guidelines or criteria for evaluating publications, maybe considering the discipline.

Comment: What is your academic discipline or area?

Comment: Statistical methodology and analysis

Comment: Value **to whom**?  Different fields view multiple authorship differently.  In fields where single-author papers are the norm, having five coauthors dilutes your perceived contribution; in fields where 10-author papers are the norm, it does not.  (See also: author ordering.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the question to make it clearer. Do you know how to substantiate what you say (even if it may be obvious to most of us)?

Comment: Furthermore, you might be named as a "nerd" in single author ones!!!: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56106/does-one-really-have-to-consider-having-a-co-author-to-avoid-being-considered-as

Comment: _For value I mean time and effort put in writing the papers and getting them published._ --- That sounds like _cost_, not value. I assumed "value" meant something like the work's contribution to your reputation among your peers, reputation within your department, reputation among your supervisors, collaboration potential, hiring potential, promotion potential, funding potential, attractiveness to strong PhD students, commercialization opportunities, and the like.

Comment: I'd have thought that it mainly depends on the study and is (other than deciding what to study and together with whom) no decision of the yours: if you do it single-handed, you'll have a one-author paper, if many people work together it'll be multiple authors.

Comment: Ok, it seems that i started a sterile polemic. I thought it was clear from the subject that the value was towards academic evaluation. Maybe i should gave said cost. Maybe my VP is right.